# "Snowflaked" Hausdorff metric

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, fractals, set-valued-analysis

Let $(X,d_X)$ be a compact metric space and let $Comp(X)$ be the set of closed subsets of $X$ with the Hausdorff metric:
$$
D(A,B)\overset{\text{def}}{=} \, \max\left\{\sup_{b\in B}\,d_{A}(b),\sup_{a\in A}\,d_{B}(a)\right\}.
$$
Recently, in my research, the following quantity popped up:

*Let $\alpha>0$ and define $D_{\alpha}$ on $\text{Comp}(X)$ as follows:
$
D_{\alpha}(A,B)\overset{\text{def}}{=} \, \max\left\{\sup_{b\in B}\,d_{A}^{\alpha}(b),\sup_{a\in A}\,d_{B}^{\alpha}(a)\right\}?
$*

The metric $D_{\alpha}$ seems to just be the Hausdorff distance on the snowflake $(X,d_{X}^{\alpha})$.  But I wonder, has anyone else seen this object in the literature before?

Comment: Do you assume that $\alpha\leq 1$? Otherwise $d_X^\alpha$ need not be a metric. I haven't seen $D_\alpha$, but I have seen a lot of literature about $(X,d_X^\alpha)$ spaces. I guess, you are familiar with that too, since you are using a correct term "snowflake".

Comment: Exactly; though I include the $\alpha>1$ "metric" case since it could be interesting (even if the triangle inequality degenerates).

Comment: So is $D_\alpha(A,B)=D(A,B)^\alpha$ ?